# dependent eigenvectors for one λ

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a matrix and it has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with $\text{mult}(\lambda_2)=2$, vector $v_1$ corresponds to $\lambda_1$ and vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ correspond to $\lambda_2$. Is it possible vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ to be linearly dependent? Is it true that all the vectors corresponding to one same eigenvalue are always linearly independent, if not, the dimension of the eigenspace for $\lambda_2$ is the number of the vectors constructing the basis, which is not always the number of all vectors in the eigenspace for this $\lambda$. True or false?

Comment: For this question, you have to be a little more careful about what you mean by multiplicity. Are you talking about the dimension of the eigensapce corresponding to $\lambda_2$? This is the geometric multiplicity. Or the order of $\lambda_2$ as a root for characteristic polynomial? This is the algebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. It has $2$ eigenvalues: $1$ and $2$. The eigenvalue $1$ has multiplicity $=2$. But its eigenspace is $1$-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

You have some terminology confusion here. You say you have a $3 \times 3$ matrix with two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, where $\lambda_2$ has geometric multiplicity $2$. This means that there are two subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, such that:

- The dimension of $V_1$ is $1$
- The dimension of $V_2$ is $2$
- If $x \in V_1$ then $Ax=\lambda_1 x$
- If $y \in V_2$ then $Ay=\lambda_2 y$.

Since the dimension of $V_2$ is two, that means there exist two linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$. Of course there are two linearly dependent eigenvectors too--but this doesn't matter.

Note that I said that the *geometric* multiplicity of $\lambda_2$ was $2$. It can happen that its *algebraic* multiplicity is $2$ but its *geometric* multiplicity is $1$. Then there will only be one independent eigenvector for that eigenvalue.